# Adobe AIR - listing installed applications

Tags: apache-flex, air, installed-applications

Is it possible to get list of installed AIR applications, optionally only by one vendor?

Or, is it possible to check, whether is one application (checked by name/some id/vendor) installed (this method would be preferred)

Thank you.

Comment: are you on a mac? is this for yourself? I can think of how to do it using Ruby to check the Applications directory, but I don't think you can do it directly with say an AIR application checking for installed AIR apps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not just for myself... I've prepared few small applications. And if somebody uses more than say 5 applications (small "does-one-thing" apps), it seems to be crazy to have 5 icons (or more)... so I though I'll do a little startup app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
        private function loadAIR():void
        {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
            loaderContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onInit);
            loader.load(new URLRequest("http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf"), loaderContext);
        }

        private function onInit(e:Event):void
        {
            var air:Object = e.target.content;
            try
            {
              air.getApplicationVersion("appID", "publisherID", versionDetectCallback);
            }
            catch (e:Error)
            {
              trace('air not installed');
            }
        }

        private function versionDetectCallback(version:String):void
        {
            if (version == null)
            {
                trace('app not installed');
            }
            else
            {
                trace('app version ' + version + ' installed');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Some Adobe docs on the `air.swf` James uses here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question.  I don't think there are any places on the client's computer where Adobe is storing a list of AIR apps installed on the computer, but you may be able to find it via [airdownload](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html).

Another decent alternative would be to use [Adobe AIR 2.0's Command Line Integration](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/preview-command-line-integration-in-adobe-air-2) feature.  With that you could write an OS-dependent, yet fairly simple, script  (shell, ruby, python, etc.) that recursively checked some directories for .AIR files by name, and if they weren't found, your startup app could say "Sorry we haven't found these two apps: X and Y.  Please either specify their location or download them here".  And after they specified the install path, you could infer where they might have other AIR apps installed.

Or you could install a text file in their home directory with a list of the AIR apps you have installed and read that to figure out what steps you should take next.  That would probably be easier.

Hope that helps,
Lance

Comment: text file seems like doable option - I don't know, however, if there isn't any other. I think I'll try Google with rephrased searches, thank you for ideas though.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the appID and the publisherID, adobe.utils.ProductManager might have something magical for you... but productManager is such a poorly documented class that I'm going to guess that my suggestion is a dead-end.  I used it once for something and as I recall, because of the package location, I didn't get any code insight and it was a very trial-and-error process.