# Getting the List of installed windows programs(applications) using Adobe air

Tags: windows, apache-flex, air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adobe AIR - listing installed applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265632/adobe-air-listing-installed-applications)

I'm new to Adobe air,I want to list out the installed windows programs(Applications) using adobe air..Is it possible?? Do i need to access registry keys to achieve this??